# How to find the config change history in rancher/rke?

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, rke

Is there any way to find, what all changes are made to the rancher local or downstream cluster? Is there any config change history getting maintained ? For eg : If any of my team member makes any changes to the PROD cluster then next day, How can I make sure there are no or changes happened at the cluster level ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did @Arash solution help you to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using rke 1, there is an option to get cluster state which contains the latest cluster status and changes.
Combining this with a VCS can be your answer.

1. Store rke related files in a git repo
2. Before every update, pull from the git repo
3. Run `rke util get-state-file`
4. Verify there is no modified status in your configs `git status` should do
5. You can safely `rke up`

Comment: Thanks @arash I was looking for a way in Rancher UI itself. I believe the 'rke util' will work only for the local cluster but not to the downstream cluster. Do you know if any way for the downstream cluster ?